# sequelize-auto --config option

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-auto

I have a database already built and I am using it with Sequelize ORM. The database already has timestamp columns as "created_at" and "updated_at".

To generate sequelize Models I used sequelize-auto and it generated all the models with one command. But when I use any model to fetch data. It returns error "unknown column createdAt".

Therefore I manually opened a model file and edited it with "underscored: true" and it solved the problem.
But I want this option to be set globally for all models. Therefore after googling for some time I came to know about -c option with "sequelize-auto" command.

So I created a json file and passed the path to this file in -c option. But again all the models were without "underscored: true" option.

I used this option as follows

```
sequelize-auto -o "./models" -d sequelize_auto_test -h localhost -u my_username -x my_password -e mysql -c ./config/config.json
```

I also used this command with quotes

```
sequelize-auto -o "./models" -d sequelize_auto_test -h localhost -u my_username -x my_password -e mysql -c "./config/config.json"
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the -a (--additional) flag instead of the -c to include additional model options from your JSON file.

This is what the command line help says:

```
-a, --additional       Path to a json file containing model definitions (for
                         all tables) which are to be defined within a model's
                         configuration parameter. For more info:
                         https://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/models
                         -definition/#configuration
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to write down your ./config/config.json just simple:

```
{
   "underscored": true
}
```

On my case, i'm already have the created_at and updated_at, so lets the sequelize not retrieve automatically and including schema, i have to set on my config :

```
{ 
   "timestamps": false,
   "schema": "sch_hrms"
}
```

then, execute again sequelize-auto.

All models will auto include that options.

-ManzTIHAGI